# How to run multithreading scraper

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I want to run a scraper.

```
from threading import Thread
from scraper import Scraper

def start(i: int):
    s = Scraper("de",i,10)
    s.scrape()


d = dict()


for i in range(10):
    d[i] = Thread(target=start, args=(i,))
```

The above script only executes one scraper. I want to run 10 scrapers.
Each scraper is using `requests` to **scrape** a tenth of a target url list.
What am I doing wrong? What info do you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import Thread
from scraper import Scraper

def start(i: int):
    s = Scraper("de",i,10)
    s.scrape()
d = {i:Thread(target=start, args=(i,)) for i in range(10)}
[d[i].start() for i in range(10)]
```